# Speed up performance of R Script, Performance changes between runs

Tags: r, performance, time

I have a script that I want to run a couple of times (5000 - 10 000). The speed seems to be around 0.10 sec usually, but sometimes it goes up to 1-2 seconds and other times even up to 7 sec. It's not that common that it go up to this time, but I would like to know why this could happen.

I have a script-file calling other script-files. My only warnings are these: 
`"closing unused connection #NUMBER"`, which I'm trying to fix.

I try to use `rm()` in the end of each script-file.

My script writes and reads to some files, xml and txt.

Does anyone have any idea of what could be the problem? I know it's hard, but maybe someone have experience from this (that the time that a script takes changes).

I would also appreciate any tip of how I can search the "problem". I'm a bit of a beginner in this, maybe there's a good guide of debugging in R?

Thanks!

Comment: Does garbage collection (`gc()`) help?

Comment: When the file size or format (xml/txt) differs this could of course change the execution time. You could add ``system.time({  your script  })`` and save the output time somewhere. Maybe you could identify the "evil files" and get a solution this way.

Comment: Sure, I do use system.time. But the file don't change size, maybe only the output from another program, but I dont think that it would neither. I write data to an xml and txt file. After I run a program that gives me outdata, then I collect the outdata and do a new run. 

So I know when it's slow, but I don't know why, or how to get more info :) ( I also look how much time the program takes, so it's not in my "time for script")

Comment: Tried gc(), thanks for the tip. But where should I use it? Now I use it before each iteration, I don't think it made much difference. The script always do the same thing, enter values to file, wait for program, read output, so that should take about the same time. Should I use gc() everywhere? :p